# Delivey Pipeline plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, delivery-pipeline

We are using the '[Delivery Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)' plugin in Jenkins. We have defined a view called '**DeliveryPipeline**'. The view takes a job called '**Initialize**'
as its initial job.

---

It shows the build numbers for the initial job as depicted in the below pic, which is the default behavior for a normal job:
[image]

---

**So, when I click on any build number; say 38, it opens the following page:**
[image]

---

But, expectation is , on clicking on the build number(say 38 here) in the initial job '**Initialize**', the below page should be shown (which is the pipeline view for build 38) :
[image]

---

How can we accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Build Plugin Graph View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Graph+View+Plugin) plugin, which gives the same output what you are expecting.

For more information in accessing Build Graph, visit the wiki page of the plugin.